# Prioritising Netty tasks in ThreadPoolExecutors

Tags: netty

I have a server implemented in netty which handles a user request, talks to a middleware, and sends a response. The I/O is expected to be negligible compared to the round-trip to the middleware, so to minimise blocking I have an ExecutionHandler in the pipeline on top of an OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor. No problems so far.

I'm looking into how the server behaves under heavy load. From past experience with our protocol, we tend to get swamped by accidental DOS attacks - most often, a user's script stuck in an infinite loop, or similar. Ideally we could de-prioritise their channels once they pass a certain usage threshold, so that other users' service isn't affected.

I've implemented a simple ThreadPoolExecutor which uses a PriorityBlockingQueue and sets priority based on data extracted from our own Session class (attached to the context in the ChannelHandler). Again, no problems so far.

The difficulty comes when trying to take advantage of the ordering and memory awareness of netty's built-in ThreadPoolExecutors. Ideally MyThreadPoolExecutor could just extend OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor and wire in the priority queue stuff. Alas this isn't possible for two reasons: private and final. In more detail:

a) ThreadPoolExecutor.workQueue can be set in its constructor, but MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor hard-codes this as a LinkedTransferQueue, and doesn't expose this to its child OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor (i.e. MyThreadPoolExecutor doesn't have access to set it). If necessary this can be overcome with an ugly bit of reflection-based private field tweaking.

b) I would like to be able to override MyThreadPoolExecutor.doUnorderedExecute(), so that I can insert the priority-handling and construct the necessary objects, but it's declared final. The code which calls it doesn't need to be changed.

The upshot is that to keep all the nice netty features, but use a priority queue, I would have to copy'n'paste both OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor and MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor, tweak a couple of lines of each, and then extend from there. This doesn't strike me as good coding practice! Even considering it sets off alarm bells.

Now to a few questions:

1) Am I solving the wrong problem? Am I barking up entirely the wrong tree for what I want to achieve?

2) If not, is there a better way of doing this than those discussed above?

3) The above approach brings with it a risk of starvation for the de-prioritised tasks where the total server load is consistently at capacity. I'm prepared to tolerate this for 'naughty' users, but as soon as they are returned to normal status, their existing tasks will still be starving, and to preserve ordering any new, higher-priority tasks must be added behind them. Do you have any recommendations of how best to deal with this? (Banning users is not allowed by the business.)

4) This is half-question, half-feedback. The netty documentation for OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor has a handy diagram for thread X & Y - presumably these are the threads pooled in the ThreadPoolExecutor and not I/O worker threads? It may be worth making this more clear. Also, when not using an ExecutionHandler, each channel is bound to a single I/O worker thread - is this still the case when behind an ExecutionHandler? i.e. is the order that tasks are added to the ExecutionHandler guaranteed to be the same as the order they arrive in the Channel? If this is the case, then I cannot see how Thread X in the docs for MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor could process event 2 before event 1 - I accept that here different threads can finish work in any order, but I can't see how the work can be assigned to the same thread out of order (it pops from workQueue). The docs in ExecutionHandler hint at this but would benefit from a little more detail.

Thanks a lot for reading, and any help is richly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1) No, you're idea is fine.  It's just `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor` that lacks such feature.  Would you [file an issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues)?

2) I would just fork `OrderedMemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor`, simplify it, and add priority queue. That way, you have much more control over how queue items (events) are processed.

3) Instead of using a priority queue, you could have two queues - one for high priority items and the other for lower priority items.  The thread could process the high priority queue first, but you can control the loop so that it doesn't stay there too long.

4) Yes, they are the threads from `ThreadPoolExecutor`.  If it's not clear, we should update our documentation.  Please feel free to file an issue or contribute directly by forking it.

Comment: Thanks, I will crack on with these changes, and if I get permission from my employer I will submit it to the project in due course.

Comment: I suggest a more elegant solution than two queues or a PriorityQueue. OMATPE is implemented such that a Channel's queue of tasks is given, via the main workQueue, to a Worker, which executes all that channel's tasks (and any added in the mean-time) before returning and getting another channel's work. Thus a busy channel can monopolise a worker. Therefore, for a low-priority channel, process up to a fixed number of tasks, then push it back on the tail of the workQueue. Thus it's processed without starvation, but with a cap on how much it can hog resources. (Extra overhead, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Your 'alarm bell' solution looks familiar - just start with a small pool size.

You seem to saying you need a solution for a slow server.
You might want to look at why your server slows down under load.
- thread contention (race) issues.
- initial pool sizes
- GC configuration

Comment: This server is still in development, but the (C++) one it is replacing is strongly database-bound. We solved the possibility of high load taking down the database (v. bad news) with a limited pool of worker threads, but this then admitted the possibility of one hungry user chomping up all the workers and worsening the service of everyone else (we have pretty tight SLAs to keep to). Our solution to this problem in the old server was based on assumptions which do not hold under netty, so we have to come up with something better - hence the question. We aren't worrying about pool size yet!